# How to send keys to the website using their element IDs in C# ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

In the following application, I used HTML agility pack to extract the HTML document from the given url. Now I need to know how can i use the element ids from the HTML document and enter text in the fields and in the end hit SUBMIT button to submit the form.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Url = "https://something.com/login.asp"; 
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb(); 
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);
}
```

The current application automate the web data entry.

Comment: Have you tried using a web testing framework such as Selenium (http://seleniumhq.org/)? That might do what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)         
{
    IWebDriver driver = 
        new InternetExplorerDriver(@"C:\.....\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.25.2"); 

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://website.com/login.asp");

    // Find the text input element by its name
    // username

    IWebElement name_ID = driver.FindElement(By.Name("name_ID"));
    name_ID.SendKeys("xyzw");

    // password
    IWebElement pwd_PW = driver.FindElement(By.Name("pwd_PW"));
    pwd_PW.SendKeys("fasdfasfdasdf");

    // submit login form
    IWebElement sSubmit = driver.FindElement(By.Name("submit"));
    submit.Submit();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    driver.Quit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HtmlAgilityPack does not work like that. You are simply holding a data-structure that represents the nodes in the HTML document, you are not hosting an instance of a web browser or client.

The soliutin is to traverse the HtmlDocument instance and locate the right `<form>` element then extract the appropriate child `<input />` elements. You'll need to create your own HttpWebRequest object and manually populate its `RequestStream` with an appropriately-encoded key/value pairs (assuming it's a POST form and not a GET form).

If the form you want to submit is static and won't be changing then you don't need to use HtmlAgilityPack at all, just hard-code the form names and values into your HttpWebRequest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar but I'm getting the page html manually.

```
// do webrequest stuff and return raw html
string html = DemoDoHttpGet(url, cookieContainer);

// I'm hitting an asp.net page so I have to repeat a bunch of values back to the server
// key is the "name" attribute of an element i want to find in the html
// i gathered these manually by watching a normal exchange with fiddler
var fields = new Dictionary<string, string>();
fields.Add(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode("__LASTFOCUS"), string.Empty);
fields.Add(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode("__EVENTTARGET"), string.Empty);
fields.Add(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode("__EVENTARGUMENT"), string.Empty);
fields.Add(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode("__VIEWSTATE"), string.Empty);
fields.Add(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode("__EVENTVALIDATION"), string.Empty);
fields.Add(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode("ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24Login1%24LoginButton"), string.Empty);

// this method searches the html for elements with the given names and updates
// the value for each item in the field collection with the value sent from the server
Scraper.GetFieldValues(fields, html);

/* looks kind of like this

        var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        var names = new List<string>();
        foreach (var ditem in fields)
        {
            names.Add(ditem.Key);
        }

        foreach (var nitem in names)
        {
            // find items, read value

            string xpath = string.Format("//*[@name=\"{0}\"]", (nitem));
            var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath);

            // if node found read whatever attribute is appropriate,
            // write value back to fields collection

*/

// here i'm manually providing values for login username/password
fields.Add(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(
    "ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24Login1%24UserName"), "my@email.aaa");
fields.Add(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(
    "ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24Login1%24Password"), "mypassword");

// another webrequest to post back to the server

var request2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request2.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
request2.Method = "POST";
request2.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

var args = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var item in fields)
{
    args.Append(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(item.Key));
    args.Append("=");
    args.Append(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(item.Value));
    args.Append("&");
}

using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = 
    new System.IO.StreamWriter(request2.GetRequestStream()))
{
    writer.Write(args.ToString().TrimEnd('&'));
}

string html;
using (var response2 = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request2.GetResponse())
using (var rdr2 = new System.IO.StreamReader(response2.GetResponseStream()))
{
    html = rdr2.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: I have used Selenium drivers to grab the html document of the page and then find the textbox or button and send keys.